# Apache Wicket - Forms

Tags: wicket, wicket-6, wicket-7

Hello I am new to Apache Wicket, can someone help me find some documentation or examples related to Apache Wicket Forms where I can navigate between a flow of screens having Text fields, Drop downs, Back and Next button.

I tried a simple example with two screens where i can navigate between the two screens. The issue that i am facing is I am unable to see the form data that i entered in the first screen on click of "Back" button from my second page and also I am not able to see the data that i entered in second screen on clicking "Next" button from 1st screen.

Comment: Can you share what you have done , There are many ways you can pass the data one to another page .

Answer (score 1):

You could use `org.apache.wicket.extensions.wizard.Wizard`.

First define your wizard steps like this:

```
private final class UserFieldsStep extends WizardStep {
    public UserFieldsStep() {
        super(new ResourceModel("adduser.title"), new ResourceModel("adduser.summary"));

        add(new RequiredTextField("user.name"));

        add(new RequiredTextField("user.email").add(EmailAddressValidator.getInstance()));

        add(new TextArea("user.description"));
    }
}
```

And then

```
public class AddUserWizard extends Wizard {
    public AddUserWizard(String id) {
        super(id);

        ....

        WizardModel model = new WizardModel();

        model.add(new UserNameStep());

        // initialize the wizard with the wizard model we just built
        init(model);
    }
}
```

More examples are available here: http://examples7x.wicket.apache.org/wicket-examples/wizard/

http://examples7x.wicket.apache.org/wicket-examples/wizard/wicket/bookmarkable/org.apache.wicket.examples.source.SourcesPage?2&SourcesPage_class=org.apache.wicket.examples.wizard.WizardPage

Comment: Hi Roman. I looked at the examples in the link that you have provided. I am trying to achieve something which is similar to one of the examples "wizard for creating a new user" my requirement is i have a flow of 4 screens with text fields and drop downs and on the 5th screen the user will validate all the information captured from the 4 screens and on click of submit need to call a micro-service to persist the data. Can I achieve this by following this example.

Comment: Yes, you can. In the example they use a `CompoundPropertyModel` `setDefaultModel(new CompoundPropertyModel<>(this));` to collect all the data entered on all wizard steps to the same model. Then on the last step you can display the data out of that model and then implement your 'finishing' logic (like calling a microservice) inside `onFinish()` method.